# Error in creating a AsyncTask getting images from online?

Tags: android

Here is where i am getting a error at.. in the doInBackground in my asynctask

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask{

```
                protected void onPreExecute(){
                    try {
                            getImages();
                            Log.v("MyTask", "Image 1 retreived");
                            getImage2();
                            Log.v("MyTask", "Image 2 retreived");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e("MainMenu retreive image", "Image Retreival failed");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                }

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                    ((Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery))
                            .setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
                        return null;
                }

                        }

}
```

I get a syntax at new ImageAdapter(this)) in my async task.. Here is how i have it contructed.

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    myGames = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myGames);
    newRelease = (Button)findViewById(R.id.newRelease);
    gameNews = (Button)findViewById(R.id.news);
    gameNews.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainMenu.this, GameNews.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    }); MyTask myTask = new MyTask();

    myTask.execute();

}


public void getImages() throws IOException{

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("https://sites.google.com/site/theitrangers/images/webImages.txt");
    HttpResponse response;

        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


            HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

            BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

            InputStream is = buf.getContent();


            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line + "\n");

              imageUrl = total.toString();
              Log.v("getImage2", "Retreived image");
            }

            }
            public void getImage2() throws IOException{

                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("https://sites.google.com/site/theitrangers/images/webImage2.txt");
                HttpResponse response;


                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


                        HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

                        BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

                        InputStream is = buf.getContent();


                        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                        String line;
                        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                            total.append(line + "\n");

                          imageUrl2 = total.toString();
                          Log.v("getImage2", "Retreived image");
                        }

}
            public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
                /** The parent context */
                private Context myContext;public ImageAdapter() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                }
                /** URL-Strings to some remote images. */

                private String[] myRemoteImages = {imageUrl,imageUrl2};






                /** Simple Constructor saving the 'parent' context. */
                public ImageAdapter(Context c) { this.myContext = c; }





                /** Returns the amount of images we have defined. */
                public int getCount() { return this.myRemoteImages.length; }

                /* Use the array-Positions as unique IDs */
                public Object getItem(int position) { return position; }
                public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }

                /** Returns a new ImageView to
                * be displayed, depending on
                * the position passed. */
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ImageView i = new ImageView(this.myContext);

                try {
                                /* Open a new URL and get the InputStream to load data from it. */
                                URL aURL = new URL(myRemoteImages[position]);
                                URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
                                conn.connect();

                                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();  
                                /* Buffered is always good for a performance plus. */
                                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                                /* Decode url-data to a bitmap. */
                                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                                bis.close();
                                is.close();
                                Log.v(imageUrl, "Retrieving image");

                                /* Apply the Bitmap to the ImageView that will be returned. */
                                i.setImageBitmap(bm);
                        } catch (IOException e) {

                                Log.e("DEBUGTAG", "Remtoe Image Exception", e);
                        }

                /* Image should be scaled as width/height are set. */
                i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                /* Set the Width/Height of the ImageView. */
                i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 150));
                return i;
                }

                /** Returns the size (0.0f to 1.0f) of the views
                * depending on the 'offset' to the center. */
                public float getScale(boolean focused, int offset) {
                /* Formula: 1 / (2 ^ offset) */
                return Math.max(0, 1.0f / (float)Math.pow(2, Math.abs(offset)));
                }
                }






                private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

                protected void onPreExecute(){
                    try {
                            getImages();
                            Log.v("MyTask", "Image 1 retreived");
                            getImage2();
                            Log.v("MyTask", "Image 2 retreived");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e("MainMenu retreive image", "Image Retreival failed");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                }

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                    ((Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery))
                            .setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
                        return null;
                }

                        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting in the name of your activity in there as well.  somehting like 
      .setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(MainMenu.this));

Answer (score 0):

```
 URL aURL = new URL(myRemoteImages[position]);
 URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
 conn.connect();
```

Log the URLs that you are connecting to. I suspect there is something wrong there. That exception comes when the URLs are not proper.

Comment: Why not? NullPointer? Try Logging the value of this myRemoteImages[position]

Comment: Theres nothing wrong with the URL im setting it in code. so there error cant be there

Comment: Perhaps, more of your log would help point out the problem. Try and check the log at which exact line of your code it raises this exception.

Comment: When i took the statement in onCreate - ((Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery))
        .setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this)); out of my code it worked fine. I set Log.v for all the image retreivals and they were retreived from the URL sucessfully

Comment: Please post a more detailed log. It's not enough for someone to guess.